# How to make State Hook asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the value of a counter on user click. 
The problem is that the state isn't synchronous, so the counter isn't updating properly and has one step late.

Here is the state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ count: 2, read: true });

const { count, read } = state;
```

The user first click on an element, call a reset function :

```
const onReset = e => {
  setState({ count: 0, read: false });
  getArticles(article.slug, count, count + 2);
};
```

Then, the user can hit a `load more` button which increments the counter.

```
const loadMore = e => {
  if (read) {
    getArticles(article.slug, count, count + 2)
  } else {
   getTagArticles(article.slug, count, count + 2);
  }

  setState({ ...state, count: count + 2 });
};
```

How can I make it asynchronous so my counter isn't late on updating the value? Should I use global variables instead of a state hook?

Thanks